# Issues with spaces when executing powershell script from the command line

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the following script from the command with parameters. However I get this error, what am I doing wrong?

```
-File & "'C:\BB2 Images\MoveFiles.ps1'" -destinationRoot "\\OB-VM-ME-Data\ME-Data\Archived\BusbarTools\BB-2" -localPath & "'C:\BB2 Images'"
```

> Processing -File ''C:\BB2 Images\MoveFiles.ps1'' failed: The given path's format is not supported. Specify a valid path for the -File parameter.

Comment: Why do you use `"` and `'`?

Comment: I had read on here that was how to tackle the problem. But it did not work

Comment: Try `-File &("C:\BB2 Images\MoveFiles.ps1")`

Comment: Well the error is different now. it say -destinationRoot was unexpected at this time. Which is one of m parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the path is quoted as a string, most Powershell commands/functions handle spaces in the file path themselves. (see [about_quoting_rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) for difference between `" "` and `' '`)

So only use one set of quotes in your command, you also don't need to use the `&` either:

```
[powershell] -File "C:\BB2 Images\MoveFiles.ps1" -destinationRoot "\\OB-VM-ME-Data\ME-Data\Archived\BusbarTools\BB-2" -localPath "C:\BB2 Images"
```

The `&` is used when calling a command (not when calling a file):

```
powershell -Command "& {<command>}"
```

Comment: Good advice, but just to clarify: you don't _need_ `& { ... }` to invoke a command: `powershell -Command "<command>"` is sufficient; that is, there is no need to wrap a command in an extra script block. However, you do need `&` inside `<command>` to invoke a command name/path specified as a _variable_ or a _quoted_ string.