# How to preserve multiple spaces as a string argument for powershell in cmd in Windows 10

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-10

I am trying to run a powershell command with several string arguments via cmd.

The context is that I want to use the `Compress-Archive` cmdlet from a Matlab function/script. And Matlab only has access to cmd.

But I can't find a way to preserve consecutive spaces in the string arguments when calling `powershell.exe` in cmd.

```ps
C:\Users\Artus>powershell.exe echo 'a   c'
a c

C:\Users\Artus>powershell.exe echo \"a   c\"
a c

C:\Users\Artus>powershell.exe echo `"a   c`"

c`

C:\Users\Artus>powershell.exe echo \"`'a   c`'\"
'a c'
```

I tried to adapt the answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502602/issues-with-spaces-when-executing-powershell-script-from-the-command-line), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130452/powershell-keep-multiple-spaces) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60550500/powershell-run-cmd-with-spaces-in-argument) questions and none worked.

How does one avoid the removal of consecutive spaces when passing arguments to powershell.exe? Is there a way to ask powershell.exe to accept an argument as string literal?

Comment: `powershell.exe "echo 'a    c'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an explanation to [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo)'s effective solution:

```bash
# Use of "..." around the entire argument is the key.
# (The extra space before and after the command is just for visual clarity.)
powershell.exe " echo 'a    c' "

# Alternative with embedded double-quoting
powershell.exe " echo \"a    c\" "
```

That is, **enclosing the *entire command* in `"..."` is necessary to avoid the *whitespace normalization* you saw.**

---

When you pass a *command* (piece of PowerShell code) to the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter (which is *positionally implied* in your case), PowerShell performs the following command-line parsing *first*, by splitting the command line into:

- white-space separated tokens
- with *double*-quoted tokens (`"..."`) getting recognized as single tokens even if they contain spaces, with the interior spaces getting preserved as-is; note that these (unescaped) `"` are *removed* in the process).

  - Note: By contrast, `'...'`-enclosed tokens are *not* recognized as single tokens on the command line (even though inside a PowerShell session they are), so that `'a     b'` is split into *verbatim* `'a` and `b'`.

The resulting tokens are then joined with a *single space* to form the single string that is *then* interpreted and executed as PowerShell code.

It is during the splitting by whitespace - which can be *any* number of spaces between tokens - that the information about *how many* spaces there were between tokens is lost.

Only inside `"..."`-enclosed tokens is the whitespace preserved as-is, hence the use of `"..."` around the entire command above.

**If you need to use `"` quoting *as part of the PowerShell command*** (to use string interpolation), `"` characters must be **escaped as `\"`**, as shown in the second command at the top.
However, **if you're calling from `cmd.exe` / a batch file, this may *break*** due to how `cmd.exe` parses command lines. In such edge cases, use the **workarounds** discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375).